# Moving an underlined <div> under the title and positioned to the left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move this div to the left under the title, but I cant seem to do it with text-align or justify content, those are my usual methods for centering. However, I want this div to move to the left.

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYmQC.png)

```css
.grid-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
}

.section-title {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline {
  background: #F4D06F;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text {
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<article class="about-container">
  <div class="title">
    <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
    <div class="title_underline"></div>
    <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Saepe illo quae ea nulla quas quia eaque omnis maxime tenetur molestiae eveniet at laboriosam provident, quibusdam quo sit expedita similique earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="about_image">
    <img src="img/bravo.jpg" class="about_img" alt="about-img">
  </div>
</article>
<!--about column 1-->
```

Comment: Why not use a bottom border ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need a useless extra empty `<div>`, just a `:after` pseudo:

```css
.title_name {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_name:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background: #F4D06F;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Comment: even a `<hr>` element between the `<h1>` and `<p>` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a `div` it defaults to `display: block;`, so you'll need to set it to `display: inline-block;`.

```
.title_underline
{
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```